# Improper use of php sort() function?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I want to sort a string ($title) alphabetically

original code:

```
  foreach ($feed->get_items() as $item) {
    $title = $item->get_title();
    echo $title.'</br>';
    }
```

Returns:
Auction 95, 15. March 2008
Electronic Auction 153
Antike Münzen
The William Stancomb collection of coins of the Black Sea region
Münzen und Medaillen A.G., Liste 366.
Collection R. Jameson
Monetele citilor din Dobrogoea
[Untitled]
Select Greek Coins

I thought to sort a string, I have to turn the sting into an array, sort the array, and turn it back into a string.

For instance:

```
foreach ($feed->get_items() as $item) {
//added '#' so I could it explode it based on something
$title = $item->get_title().'#'; 
$titleArray = explode("#",$title);
sort($titleArray);
echo implode('#', $titleArray).'</br>';
 }
```

Returns:
(the exact same thing)

I have been trying lots of different versions of turning it to an array and trying to sort the array to no avail. I am a (obviously) beginner that needs help. Any hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort the array ***before*** iterating through it

```
$array = $feed->get_items();
usort(
    $array,
    function ($a, $b) {
        return strcmp($a->get_title(), $b->get_title());
    }
);
foreach ($array as $item) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: You saved me thank you. I don't have enough reputation points to do +1

Answer (score 2):

Use [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)

```
$array = $feed->get_items();
usort($array, function($a, $b) {
    if ($a->get_title() == $b->get_title()) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a->get_title() < $b->get_title()) ? -1 : 1;
});
```

`$array` contains the sorted items.

Comment: Also wonderful, but I don't have enough reputation points to do +1